# How to Split One Excel Sheet into many Sheets According to its Criteria

Tags: excel, vb.net, split

I want to split one worksheet which has a column named Diameter into many sheets according to the number of diameters found, in my case it is Column C in a Master Sheet,
My code is

```
Private Sub Splitter()
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Source As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Destination As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim DestinationRow As Long
    Dim Diameter As String
    xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("E:\Patches\Main_Master_VB.xlsm")
    Source = wb.Worksheets("Master")
    Lastrow = Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "C").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    For SourceRow = 2 To Lastrow
        Diameter = Source.Cells(SourceRow, "C").Value
        Destination = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Destination Is Nothing Then
            Destination = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
            Destination.Name = Diameter
            Source.Rows(1).Copy(Destination.Rows(1))
        End If
        DestinationRow = Destination.Cells(Destination.Rows.Count, "C").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
        Source.Rows(SourceRow).Copy(Destination:=Destination.Rows(DestinationRow))
    Next SourceRow
    xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I receive error Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))' at the Line `Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter)`

Notice : this code is running with VBA but not running with VB.net

Appreciate your help

Thanks, Regards

Moheb Labib

Comment: Then text from your error message ("Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter") is not in your code. Also you code lacs indentation for better readability.

Comment: `Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter.ToString)` ..... Diameter is a String, and `Sheets()` do not accept a string, but an index.

Comment: @luuk, It is in my code but with .tostring, `Destination = wb.Sheets(Diameter.ToString)`

Comment: @luuk, this code is running correct in VBA, So how I use Index?

Comment: ok i have excel2013 and it is complaining about the string... You have defined `Diameter` as string, why are you doing `Diameter.ToString` ?

Comment: @luuk, Sorry, it was a trial, I edited the code above

Comment: `Workbook.Sheets()` should not have a string (like `Diameter`) as  parameter, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixes compilation errors caused by Option Strict disliking late binding. It may help point our what is wrong with the code.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Private Sub Splitter()
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Source As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Destination As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim DestinationRow As Long
    Dim Diameter As String
    xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("E:\Patches\Main_Master_VB.xlsm")
    Source = CType(wb.Worksheets("Master"), Worksheet)
    Dim RowCount = Source.Rows.Count
    Dim LastRowRange = CType(Source.Cells(RowCount, "C"), Range)
    Lastrow = LastRowRange.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    For SourceRow = 2 To Lastrow
        Dim DiameterRange = CType(Source.Cells(SourceRow, "C"), Range)
        Diameter = DiameterRange.Value.ToString
        Destination = Nothing
        'On Error Resume Next
        Destination = CType(wb.Sheets(Diameter), Worksheet)
        'On Error GoTo 0
        If Destination Is Nothing Then
            '                   (Before, After, Count, Type)
            Destination = CType(wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)), Worksheet)
            Destination.Name = Diameter
            Dim row = CType(Source.Rows(1), Range)
            row.Copy(Destination.Rows(1))
        End If
        Dim DestinationRowRange = CType(Destination.Cells(Destination.Rows.Count, "C"), Range)
        DestinationRow = DestinationRowRange.End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row + 1
        Dim SourceRowRange = CType(Source.Rows(SourceRow), Range)
        SourceRowRange.Copy(Destination:=Destination.Rows(DestinationRow))
    Next SourceRow
    xl.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, however it gives an error in the same line of code `Destination = CType(wb.Sheets(Diameter), Worksheet)` as invalid index error?

Comment: Can you check the value of Diameter? Directly below `Diameter = DiameterRange.Value.ToString` add a line `Debug.Print(Diameter)` I seem to remember that Excel sticks a $ in front of sheet names. That could be the problem.

Comment: @Meho2016 Just for grins try `Diameter = DiameterRange.Value.ToString & "$"`  I checked some old Excel code and there seems to be a $ following the sheet name.

Comment: Thanks but it gives the same error, I think the point is this code is working in vba without any error at all, if yo want I can paste you the VBA Code to Check